# conAdd.txt file

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, python-3.3

I am opening a text file with python. The text has "sub 5 10".python opens the text file andsubtracts it. But when I add an else function it just does the else it doesnt subtract it. Instead it adds it even tho my text file says sub.

```
def main():
    infi = open ("condAdd.txt", "r")
    nList = infi.readline().split()
    sub = 0
    add = 0
    if sub=="sub":
        num2 = eval(nList[2])
        num1 = eval(nList[1])
        subt = num1-num2
        print(subt)
    else:
        num4 = eval(nList[2])
        num3 = eval(nList[1])
        adde = num3+num4
        print (adde)
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use `eval()` when `int()` would do:

```
num2 = int(nList[2])
# etc.
```

You are testing the wrong variable; test `nList[0]` instead:

```
if nList[0] == "sub":
```